# Unable to install package manually

Tags: python, pandas, pip, pycharm, pypi

I'm using PyCharm as an IDE, I want to install packages manually (as i'm behind a firewall and can't get PIP to connect to PyPi directly on this machine.

I have downloaded the package manually from PyPi and stored it in a suitable location. When referencing that package directly in pip install I am getting a timeout message.

```
C:\Users\username>pip install C:\users\username\python_dateutil-2.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

```
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000023CAE8EA278
>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/six/
```

Why is it trying to connect externally still, even though I've already downloaded the package.

What am I doing wrong? I hope its not the beer. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you are behind a firewall (or at least PyCharm is). You may need to download the package and install it locally with `pip install -e \path\to\package`.

Comment: That's exactly what I am doing. In the PyCharm terminal I am referencing the already downloaded package with the following code: C:\Users\username>pip install C:\users\username\python_dateutil-2.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl. You must not have read my queastion :)

Comment: Maybe it's trying to install dependencies. You need to install all of them manually as well.

Comment: it tries to install `six`. Install all dependencies first

Comment: You got it :)  thanks for that

Comment: You can also find out if there's a proxy, then configure `pip` / `PyCharm` to use it, so you can install like normal.